# How to avoid ambiguity in the sentence“This is a little used car”?

Tags: adjectives, punctuation, ambiguity, hyphens

Here’s a sentence which  is open to two interpretations and therefore can’t be grammatical:

> “This is a little used car”.

To avoid the ambiguity of the meaning, would it be enough just to insert a comma between the above two (maybe reversing the position of “used” and “little”) so that it would mean ***a used/second-hand car that is not large in size?***

> This is a little, used car.
>
> This is a used, little car.

What is the way to emphasize that the car (no matter what its size is) ***has been used for a short time***?

I’m thinking of using a hyphen:

> This is a little-used car

But I’m not sure about whether it would be correct.

Anyway, being read aloud, both *“a little, used”* and *“a little-used”* to me, a non-native English speaker, sound pretty much alike.

Are there other ways of expressing the very same ideas in oral speech for them to be clearly understood?

**An addition:**

Not having received the answer so far, I feel like adding to my question the following:

From what I have been able to gather by now, one of the main functions of hyphens (separating words into parts being kept in mind) is combining separate words into a single word to clarify meanings,  removing ambiguities from sentences. Gluing words together hyphens notify the reader that two or more elements in a sentence are linked.

At the [GrammarBook.com](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp) site (Rule 5) there’s a recommendation never to hesitate to add a hyphen if it may solve a possible problem of ambiguity. In this regard, might a hyphen gluing “used” and “car” together (“*This is a little **used-car***”) help solve the problem so that the meaning were “*not large in size, used car*”? If there’s a restriction (@stangdon in his comment says there is) on using hyphens to link an adjective and the noun it modifies,  can’t it be ignored by writers for the sake of clarity?

Comment: Little can be both an adjective and an adverb, it is an adverb in this case so it is grammatical. There are other little + adjective combinations which do use a hyphen probably to avoid the ambiguity you are worried about (little-known for example) Of course you could always use adverbs that dont allow  any ambiguity such as "rarely" in this case.

Comment: I'd say, "This is a low-mileage,  small pre-owned car in good condition."

Comment: Inserting a comma, no matter in which order "little" and "used"are, suggests that the noun (car in this case) has both the traits because then both little and used would be adjectives and little wouldnt modify "used". Little used or little-used mean that the car was rarely used.

Comment: Your examples are correct and good.  Even in speech, there is a difference between "little-used" and "little, used".  "Little-used" is pronounced like a single word of three syllables, with emphasis on "little".  "Little, used" has a momentary pause between the words, and "used" would be stressed.  But using less-ambiguous terms is more reliable.

Comment: You're fine with the hyphen to indicate a car that has not been used much. Otherwise, there can be two interpretations: "A little, used car" (with comma) means a car that is both little and used. "A little used car" (no comma) means a car that is little by the standards applicable to used cars. In speech, a slight pause after "little" in the first of those would help disambiguate. And a slight emphasis on "used" in the latter example would help.

Comment: I second the recommendation for a hyphen.  It makes it clear that the two words are to be interpreted as one phrase.

Comment: @stangdon - What about a little used-car? Would this be correct too?

Comment: @Rompey - No, "a little *used-car*" doesn't make sense.  *little* modifies the adjective *used*; that's why there can be a hyphen between them.  But we don't put a hyphen between an adjective and the noun it modifies.

Comment: @Rompey - To expand on that a little, you will sometimes see what looks like a hyphen between an adjective and a noun that it modifies, like *blue-dog* in [*blue-dog Democrat*](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2000/12/what_is_a_bluedog_democrat.html).  But that's actually a case where *dog* itself is being used as an adjective!

Comment: Part of the potential for ambiguity can be removed if you refer it as a 'small, used car'.

Comment: @stangdon See my Ngram - if it doesn't make sense (which I agree with), why is it so prevalent?

Comment: @StephenS - Because you're considering "used-car" in isolation.  This is what I was addressing in my "to expand" comment: "used-car dealer" is fine, because *used-car* is modifying *dealer*, but you wouldn't write "This is a used-car."

Comment: @stangdon I see. Used-car dealer accounts for about 1/7th of all used-car usages. With other similar usages, which I really don't know how to search for, it would probably level out.

Comment: @StephenS - Try searching for "used-car *asterisk*" (sorry, I don't know how to put a literal asterisk in a comment).  That will give you the top ten results for things following *used-car*.  They're all nouns, which strongly suggests that *used-car* is almost always being used as an adjective.

Comment: @stangdon - Here's a hyphenated noun ["used-car"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/used-car). Why can't it follow the adjective "little"?

Comment: @Rompey Because in English, we don't put a hyphen between an adjective and the noun it describes.  I don't know where The Free Dictionary got that entry, but I wouldn't trust TFD as far as I could throw it.  I am pretty sure you won't find *used-car* used as a noun anywhere in live usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is a little used car.

This is how I would usually write my sentence for a small car that is used.

> This is a little, used car.

Same as above, with emphasis on its size.

> This is a used, little car.

While only native speakers would "feel" this, this **definitely** feels wrong. [This post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order) supports this - condition comes after size in adjective order. (See the bullets in the top answer)

> This is a little-used car.

This is how I would express a barely used car. I have seen and used this word myself. Note that there is a difference in pronunciation between "little-used" and "little used" - the pause between the words is more pronounced for the latter.

> This is a little used-car.

I would never construct this sentence, and I have never seen it. It is very uncommon.

## However

With that said, the data shows that I was right a hundred years ago, but currently, nothing I said really holds water. See attached Google Ngram, which shows all three of my points are wrong:

- "little used" was previously very common but its usage is declining
- "little-used" is relatively uncommon compared to "little used" - but "little used" has fallen quite rapidly
- "used-car" was non-existent a hundred years ago, but has overtaken (!) "little-used" *note that this includes usages such as used-car dealer

[image: Google Ngram Viewer]

[Ngram Source](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=little-used%2Clittle%20used%2Cused-car&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Clittle%20-%20used%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blittle%20-%20used%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLittle%20-%20used%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Clittle%20used%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blittle%20used%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLittle%20used%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cused%20-%20car%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bused%20-%20car%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUsed%20-%20Car%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUsed%20-%20car%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Also - the spike of used-car around WWII is interesting. Anyone have an hypothesis?

Comment: During World War II, the major U.S. automakers switched to making airplanes, tanks, military trucks, and radar systems.  People who would normally buy new cars were forced to buy used cars.

Comment: Very good answer, indeed. Very close to what I've been looking for - let me think for a while if you get the cigar; -) Thanks awfully for the research you've done.

Comment: @Rompey Sorry that my personal beliefs disagree with the research - I was so sure I was right, until I combined the Ngrams to put into my answer, and I noticed that I was dead wrong.

Comment: @StephenS - Here's a hyphenated noun ["used-car"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/used-car). Can't it follow the adjective "little"?

Comment: @Rompey grammatically, it can. However, I've never seen it, and it looks really really wrong. Usually, you don't include a hyphen in used car. The exception is when using it as a adjective (used-car dealer as per stangdon).

Comment: You never hyphenate an adjective to the base noun it modifies. You can hyphenate when the adjective+noun forms a compound adjective that describes something else. Like used-car salesman. 

This hyphen was once mandatory for compound adjectives, but has become optional over the last 20-30 years except in cases where necessary for clarity. The side-effect of this hyphen being demoted to optional is that it too often gets left out where it's genuinely needed.

I don't think the Ngram usage data invalidates any of your earlier premises.

Answer (score 2):

No matter how you punctuate it, saying "little used car" will be ambiguous. 
 There are common synonyms of "little" and "used" that can be combined without causing this confusion.

You can use an adverb that cannot also be used as an adjective.  For example:

> - This is a barely used car.
> - This is a lightly used car.
> - This is a rarely used car.

You can indicate that the car is old, in a way that cannot be modified by an adverb that indicates extent.  If the car is old, it is not new.  If the car is not new, it is probably used.  For example:

> - This is a little 2013 car.
> - This is a little Fiero.  [Pontiac Fieros are not made anymore.  And they were all fairly small.]

You can use an adjective that describes a noun, and cannot be used to modify an adjective.  For example:

> - This is a small used car.

You can also use a compound word that incorporates one of your descriptors into the main noun.  In the context of used cars, a creampuff is a lightly-used car, and a roadster is a particular kind of small car that is fun to drive.

> - This is a creampuff.
> - This is a small creampuff.
> - This is a little creampuff.
> - This is a used roadster.

Comment: Sure, there's always more than one way to skin a cat. Thanks for the "cream puff--I've put it down.

Comment: Another is "lightly used." I think the best would be "this is a low-mileage small car."